# rsyslog unexpected end of file on log files with OMFileZipLevel

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

OS: Centos7
rsyslog: 8.24.0

I have various hosts sending logs to my centralised `rsyslog` server. I use `OMFileZipLevel` option in my config file to compress my logs and then `zcat` anytime i wish to view the contents.

Since i have upgraded to `rsyslog8`, whenever i try to `zcat` one of my compressed logs i get the following error:

```
#   zcat srv1.example.com.log.gz
2021-01-06T04:46:11-08:00 srv1.example.com lab: test_msg

gzip: srv1.example.com.log.gz: unexpected end of file
```

if i stop rsyslog server and access the file then i dont get that error message.
Even if i start the server i can still see the log file without that EOF message, **however** when my rsyslog server receives a message and writes it to the file i start getting the same message:

```
#   zcat srv1.example.com.log.gz
2021-01-06T05:54:22-08:00 srv1.example.com lab: test_msg

gzip: srv1.example.com.log.gz: unexpected end of file


#   systemctl stop rsyslog

#   zcat  srv1.example.com.log.gz
2021-01-06T05:54:22-08:00 srv1.example.com lab: test_msg


#   systemctl start rsyslog

#   zcat srv1.example.com.log.gz
2021-01-06T05:54:22-08:00 srv1.example.com lab: test_msg


srv1:~$ logger -p local5.info test_msg2 @my_rsyslog_server

#   zcat srv1.example.com.log.gz
2021-01-06T03:32:09-08:00 srv1.example.com lab: hab_test
2021-01-06T05:55:27-08:00 srv1.example.com lab: test_msg2

gzip: srv1.example.com.log.gz: unexpected end of file
```

I was able to find a mailing list where someone mentions a similar issue and this has to do with the file still been opened by rsyslog.

Thing is that i have another rsyslog server running version `5.8.10` (Centos 6) with the exact same rsyslog configuration file but i dont have such behaviour with EOF messages on my compressed logs.

Could this be a bug in rsyslog `8.24.0` ?

Comment: Since 8.3.3 dynamic files are closed only after 10 minutes idle. Perhaps it was different in 5.8.  See `closeTimeout` action parameter.

Comment: @meuh that definitely good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems a normal behaviour.
I'm not sure about `closeTimeout` parameter because `OMFileZipLevel` is usually applied to services that generates a lot of output, so I've never had a file not being written for 10 minutes (or 10 seconds btw)!

GZIP is a stream compressor, so the files are written with a header and a tail, but the tail is not written until the file is considered closed and terminated, so zcat and gunzip will complain when reaching the end of a normal gzip file that is still being written.

Using `OMFileZipLevel` just tells rsyslog to compress logs to a normal gzip file, so this still applies.

Using `veryRobustZip` rsyslog can construct gzip files composed of small blocks of gzip data concatenated one after another (which is gzip-compliant) and could allow the data to be extracted without errors with zcat or gunzip (but [consult rsyslog help](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omfile.html#veryrobustzip) to check some details).

Nonetheless, I've develop **gztool** to easily manage compressed log files produced by rsyslog, no matter the options: you can

- continuosuly tail a .log.gz file like with `tail -f` for text files, using `gztool -T`
- extract all data even if the process sending logs is abruptly stopped and then restarted, which lead to gzip files with unreachable data for zcat/gunzip but that gztool can flawlessly extract with `gztool -p`
- extract data from any part of the gzip file without reading it all (which is compulsory for other tools)

Just [consult the examples of use](https://github.com/circulosmeos/gztool/#examples-of-use) of **gztool**.

The question would be why it didn't happen before the upgrade: are you sure this didn't happen before with the same rsyslog configuration?